# Minimal set of generators VS Length of a module.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Recently, I have been  thinking about a problem in which I try to use the information I have about the set of generators of a finitely generated module over a nice ring and say something about the length of that. I don't want to post the problem and spoil the joy of thinking about that. Instead, I want to ask a bit more general question.

As long as I know, in general, it is not possible to look at the minimal set of generators and conclude something about the length. It is quite easy to make a multitude of counterexamples.

So, I would like to ask this question:

What are the weakest conditions we should put on the ring and the module in order to be able to use the information about the minimal set of generators and say something interesting about the length of the module?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ has finite length and $M$ has $n$ generators, then $\ell(M) \leq n \ell(A)$.

It's hard to say much more, as you probably know.  E.g. already over $\mathbb Z$
there are cyclic modules (so one generator) of arbitrary length.

Comment: Dear Matt, Thank you for your answer.
That inequality you mentioned is certainly true and not hard to prove. However, the ring you chose for the counterexample itself is not the best we could work on. Because, it is not Artinian, and then we loose many good properties of finitely generated modules over Artinian rings. 
I was thinking of considering the rings over which some of the properties like having finite length and being finitely generated are closely connected.

Comment: @Kaveh: Dear Kaveh, I wasn't sure what your context was. If you work over Artinian rings, then you have this inequality,  but there's not much more you can say.  E.g. by taking direct sums of simple modules you can make examples for which the number of generators equals the length.  On the other hand, if $A$ has length $l$, then you can find cyclic modules of any length between $1$ and $l$ (and then take direct sums of those). So unless $l = 1$ (so that we are just doing vector spaces over a field --- at least in the commutative case --- it is hard to do better than this inequality.)  Regards,